# Reduction of order of non-linear 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to follow the derivation on [this wolfram page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html) in which the parametric equations for the brachistochrone problem with friction is found. I am having trouble being able to move from step (29) to (30), in which this 2nd order non linear ODE:

$$ [1+y'^2 ](1+\mu y')+2(y-\mu x)y''=0\tag{29}$$

is reduced to this form:

$$ \frac{1+(y')^2}{(1+\mu y')^2} = \frac{C}{y-\mu x}\tag{30} $$

I am asking for help in understanding how this reduction is carried out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of $y-\mu x$ is $y'-μ$. To transform the equation into a form that has $F(y')y''$ on one side and something integrable on the other side, this suggests to try
$$
-\frac{y'-μ}{y−μx}=\frac{2(y'-μ)y''}{[1+y'^2](1+μy')}
$$
Now perform partial fraction decomposition for the right side,
$$
\frac{2(y'-μ)}{[1+y'^2](1+μy')}=\frac{A+By'}{1+y'^2}+\frac{C}{1+μy'}
\\\iff\\
2(y'-μ)=(A+By')(1+μy')+C[1+y'^2]
$$
which implies $C=-μB$, $2-B=μA$ and $-(2-B)μ=A$ giving $A=0$, $B=2$ and $C=−2μ$. Thus after integration of the first equation
$$
-\ln|y−μx|=\ln|1+y'^2|-2\ln|1+μy'|+c.
$$